# Java Try Catch block

Tags: java, vb.net, error-handling, try-catch

I initially started programming in college and learnt vb.net. Now I have decided to make the move to Java and have some queries. In vb, the try catch statement is laid out as follows

```
try
Catch ex as exception
finally
End catch
```

but from the java website (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/putItTogether.html)
i found that in java you use two catches like so:

```
    try {

} catch (ExceptionType name) {

} catch (ExceptionType name) {

}
```

i was hoping someone could explain why you need two catches in java and what do the respective catches do/catch.

Thanks.

Comment: A block of code may generate N types of exceptions and you could define different flows for different exceptions.

Comment: The two catches can't be the same exception type (it would be a compile-time error) - they must be different types, that you'd want to handle differently.

Comment: You don't *need* two. You can have 1..N catches that catch a different type of exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, you **can** use multiple `catch` blocks.

It doesn't necessarily means you have to.

It depends on the code your have in the `try` block, and how many checked `Exception`s it may potentially throw (or even unchecked `Exception`s if you really want to catch that, typically you don't and you don't **have to**).

One **bad** practice is to use a single handler for general `Exception` (or worse, `Throwable`, which would also catch `RuntimeException`s and `Error`s):

```
try {
    // stuff that throws multiple exceptions
}
// bad
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO
}
```

The **good** practice is to catch all potentially thrown **checked** `Exception`s.

If some of them are related in terms of inheritance, always catch the child classes first (i.e. the more specific `Exception`s), lest your code won't compile:

```
try {
    // stuff that throws FileNotFoundException AND IOException
}
// good: FileNotFoundException is a child class of IOException - both checked
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    // TODO
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    // TODO
}
```

Also take a look at Java 7's [multi-catch blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), where unrelated `Exception`s can be caught all at once with a `|` separator between each `Exception` type:

```
try (optionally with resources) {
    // stuff that throws FileNotFoundException and MyOwnCheckedException
}
// below exceptions are unrelated
catch (FileNotFoundException | MyOwnCheckedException e) {
    // TODO
}
```

**Note**

In [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/putItTogether.html) example you linked to, the first code snippet below **Putting it all together** may arguably be considered as sub-optimal: it **does** catch the potentially thrown `Exception`s, but one of them is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which is a `RuntimeException` (unchecked) and should not be handled in theory.

Instead, the `SIZE` variable (or likely constant) should be replaced by a reference to the size of the `List` being iterated, i.e. `list.size()`, in order to prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException` from being thrown.

I guess in this case it's just to provide an example though.

Answer (score 2):

The code that is on the page that is in link i have modified it with single exception. Problem here is that in this case you will not able to know that exception is where whether due to

> IndexOutOfBoundsException or IOException

just you know that a exception occurs

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        ListOfNumbers lon = new ListOfNumbers();
        lon.writeList();
    }

    private List<Integer> list;
    private static final int SIZE = 10;

    public ListOfNumbers() {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
    }

    public void writeList() {
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Entering" + " try statement");

            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("e://OutFile.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + list.get(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                System.out.println("Closing PrintWriter");
                out.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("PrintWriter not open");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let us understand the concept it is better to know why the code fails due to which particular type of exception whether

> IndexOutOfBoundsException or IOException

Now The Code with handling of different Exception

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        ListOfNumbers lon = new ListOfNumbers();
        lon.writeList();
    }

    private List<Integer> list;
    private static final int SIZE = 10;

    public ListOfNumbers() {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
    }

    public void writeList() {
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Entering" + " try statement");

            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("e://OutFile.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + list.get(i));
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IndexOutOfBoundsException: " +
                               e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                System.out.println("Closing PrintWriter");
                out.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("PrintWriter not open");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here we could come to know that whether it fails due to creation of file at location

> e://OutFile.txt
>   drive Not on my system

error printed as

> Caught Exception: e:\OutFile.txt (The system cannot find the path
>   specified) Entering try statement PrintWriter not open

Next Case

Now when i comment the line

> list.add(new Integer(i));

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ListOfNumbers {

        public static void main(String... s) {
            ListOfNumbers lon = new ListOfNumbers();
            lon.writeList();
        }

        private List<Integer> list;
        private static final int SIZE = 10;

        public ListOfNumbers() {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>(SIZE);
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                //    list.add(new Integer(i));
            }
        }

        public void writeList() {
            PrintWriter out = null;

            try {
                System.out.println("Entering" + " try statement");

                out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("OutFile.txt"));
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + list.get(i));
                }
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.println("Caught IndexOutOfBoundsException: " +
                                   e.getMessage());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());

            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    System.out.println("Closing PrintWriter");
                    out.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("PrintWriter not open");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then it clearly says that it fails for index out of bound exception

> Entering try statement Caught IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0,
>   Size: 0 Closing PrintWriter

So for the purpose of debugging the application properly and efficiently it is good.

I have created condition for the other type of exception

```
NoClassDefFoundError

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ListOfNumbers
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: stackprac.ListOfNumbers
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Exception in thread "main" Process exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.